# upload image using webservices in c# using htmlcontrol

Tags: c#, web-services

```html
 [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
     public int InsertBannerImages(string OwnerID,DateTime StrtDt,DateTime Enddt,string filename,string Zip)
     {
         
         HttpPostedFile file = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[filename];
         string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(filename);
         string filePath = "/Banner/" + OwnerID + "/BannerImages/" + Zip + file + "_banner" + fileExtension;
         string strfilelocation = "/Banner/" + OwnerID + "/BannerImages/";
         if (!Directory.Exists(strfilelocation))
         {
             Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(strfilelocation));
         }
         if (!Directory.Exists(filePath))
         {
             Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(filePath));
         }
         
         int res = objbanner.InsertBannerUpload();
         return res;
     }
```

I am trying to upload an image with web-service where the file upload control is html file upload. But I am not able to save the image in my applicaton folder

```
HttpPostedFile file = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[filename];
string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(filename);
string filePath = "/Banner/" + OwnerID + "/BannerImages/" + Zip + file + "_banner" + fileExtension;
string strfilelocation = "/Banner/" + OwnerID + "/BannerImages/";

if (!Directory.Exists(strfilelocation))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(strfilelocation));
}

if (!Directory.Exists(filePath))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(filePath));
}
```

where filename is only the image name EX: hello.jpg

Comment: Could you share the code in the front-end like Ajax for the web service? I guess, the above code is in the .asmx file.

Comment: var file = $('#txtfilecontrol').val();   Backend.InsertBannerImages(file,zip, function (responce)
            {

            });

Comment: Share full code that you are using in the front-end (HTML file - Specifically Ajax).

Comment: function Insertbanner()
        {
            var Ownerid = $('#ctl00_contentMain_ddlowner option:selected').val();
            var startDate = $('#txtStartdate').val();
            var EndDate = $('#txtEnddate').val();
            var file = $('#txtfilecontrol').val();
            var zip = $('#ddlbrshop option:selected').val();     
           
            YkioskBackend.InsertBannerImages(Ownerid, startDate, EndDate, file,zip, function (responce)
            {

            });
        }    YkioskBackend is webservice and InsertBannerImages is methord name

Answer (score 0):

First we need to get all the files from form inside html, then make a call to web service using ajax as below

```
var data = new FormData();
var files = $("#uploadcntrlid").get(0).files;

// Add the uploaded image content to the form data collection

if (files.length > 0) {  
   data.append("ImageFiles", files[0]);
}  

// Make Ajax request with the contentType = false, and procesDate = false
var ajaxRequest = $.ajax({  
      type: "POST",
      url: "fileupload.asmx/uploadfile",
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      data: data
   });
```

And inside web service(.asmx or any)

```
[WebMethod]
public void uploadfile()
{
    var imgFiles = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["ImageFiles"];
    foreach (string key in imgFiles)
    {
       HttpPostedFile file = imgFiles[key];
       string fileName = file.FileName;
       var fileSavePath = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/ImageFiles"), fileName);
       file.SaveAs(fileSavePath);
     }
}
```

Comment: Where are you receiving the data in webservice , I mean the imagefiles

Comment: `HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["ImageFiles"]` using this you will get all the files inside your form, after that u can loop through all the files

Comment: file.SaveAs(fileSavePath); throws error at this line